# use mocked object created in initializer

Tags: ios, objective-c, unit-testing, ocmock

I have a `Worker` class, its header:

```
@interface Worker : NSObject {
  // instance variable `task`
  MyTask *task;
}
@end
```

its **initialiser** method is like this:

```
@implementation Worker

-(id)initWithName:(NSString*)name{
  self = [super init];
  if (self) {
    // I need to use mocked task in my test case
    task = [[MyTask alloc] init];
    ...
    ...
  }
  return self
}

-(void)doWork{
  [task start];
}
```

I want to unit test this class, I am using [OCMock](http://ocmock.org/reference/) library to do the mock. I know I can create a mocked task by:

```
id mockedTask = OCMClassMock([MyTask class]);
```

But, **how can I inject this mocked task into my** `Worker` **instance** in test case ? I mean task is created in **initialiser** method, when I create a Worker instance in my test class:

```
-(void)setup{
  // how to inject the mocked task in to this workerUnderTest
  Worker *workerToTest = [[Worker alloc] initWithName:@"John"];
}
```

I need the mocked task to be used in test. How can I achieve it?

**==== My Test case with @iSashok's answer (it doesn't work) ====**

```
@interface WorkerTestCase : XCTestCase 
@end

@implementation WorkerTestCase{
  Worker *workerToTest;
  id mockedTask;
}
- (void)setUp {
  [super setUp];
  workerToTest = [[Worker alloc] initWithName:@"John"];

  mockedTask = OCMClassMock([MyTask class]);
  OCMStub([workerToTest task]).andReturn(mockedTask);
}

-(void) testDoWork{
 [workerToTest doWork];
 // it fails. method is not invoked!
 OCMVerify([mockedTask start]);
}
...
@end
```

As you see above, my test case fails, it complains that there is no invokation on `mockedTask` object. But when I set breakpoints to real class implementation, the `[task start]` is invoked, it indicates the `mockedTask` is not injected successfully.

Comment: Do you have any Worker attribute as task?  Worker task? Which is MyTask object.

Comment: `task` is a instance variable of `Worker` class

Comment: As you have initialiser of Worker class so you should have initialiser of MyTask class and call it from Worker class initialiser as you initialise MyTask object here. Now in setup set your workerToTest.task = mockedTask. or in testcase write OCMClassMock([MyTask initialiser method]);

Comment: Please check out existing answers. This is almost an FAQ. If you don't know what to search for: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=dependency+injection+ocmock

Answer (score 0):

You can inject it using `OCMStub()` like below and you need declare `task` ivar as a property

```
@interface Worker : NSObject 
@property(nonatomic,strong)MyTask *task;
@end
```

//

```
id mockedTask = OCMClassMock([MyTask class]);
OCMStub([workerToTest task]).andReturn(mockedTask);
```

You method will look like

```
-(void)setup{
  // how to inject the mocked task in to this workerUnderTest
  Worker *workerToTest = [[Worker alloc] initWithName:@"John"];

  id mockedTask = OCMClassMock([MyTask class]);
  OCMStub([workerToTest task]).andReturn(mockedTask);
}
```

Comment: what about partially mocked `Worker` as workerToTest?

Comment: I got compiler error "No known instance method for selector 'task'"

Comment: the same implementation. If you even stub it to full mock implementation will be the same

Comment: you need declare task as a property

Comment: does `strong` in property declaration important in this context? If so, why?

Comment: No, it's  not important, you can declare as you wanna and as need for your case

Comment: It doesn't work, why I say that is because when I verify the function calls on this mocked taks e.g. `OCMVerify([mockedTask start])`, the verify failed because the function is not invoked.

Comment: Could you provide full implementation of your test method?

Comment: Try modify your code `OCMVerify([mockedTask start]);` to `OCMVerifyAll(mockedTask);` or change `OCMStub ` to simple setter -> `workerToTest.task = mockedTask;`

Comment: I come up with a better idea, that's create another non-public initializer, pass that object as parameter, I think that is a better way to solve my problem, but thank you very much for your effort.